# jQuery callback syntax layout?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, syntax, callback

When i use a jquery function like so,

```
jQuery('.mediaContainer').dialog({ width: 500, height:500});
```

how do i set a callback? where would i place it?

thanks

Comment: It really depends on what `.dialog()` is. What kind of plugin is it? Any documentation?

Comment: @Harmen, [`dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is from jQuery UI, apparently (with thanks @Surreal Dreams).

Comment: @David, I figured it out after my comment and then I added the jquery-ui tag ;)

Comment: No thanks needed, I just Googled it :)

Comment: yes its a plugin, i am currently loading a video inside of it but when i close it and reopen the content does not reload so i need to destroy it some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dialog has several events you can set.  You can see them here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close

For instance to set an function to run on close:

```
$( ".mediaContainer" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { //do stuff }
});
```

There are a number of events you can use:  beforeClose, open, focus, dragStart, resizeStart, resize, resizeStop, and close.  Each of these events can trigger a callback function, so you actually have a lot of control.

Comment: what would i place in the even or ui arguments for example?

Comment: Leave that as it is, that's info about the event itself being passed into the function.  You can read more about the event object here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ and a ui object.  I'm pretty sure both are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it would appear after the last of the arguments in whichever method you wanted to insert the call-back into, for example:

```
jQuery('.mediaContainer').dialog({ width: 500, height:500},
   function(){
        // callback stuff here.
   });
```

This assumes that `.dialog()` is some form of plug-in, or function that will, or *can*, accept a call-back. To use a standard jQuery function ([`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)):

```
$(this).animate({'opacity': 1, 'height': '200px'}, 500, function(){
  // callback stuff.
});
```